# Retain value from select and checkbox on frontend form after failure

Tags: drop-down, checkboxes, frontend-form

I have a registration form on my frontend and when people click register but the form fails (due to the username already existing for example) I would like to keep all info they entered in the form so they don't need to enter all their data again while editing the form input that gave the error.

I know that there is an account model which you can use to keep all the info into the inputs. I used the [official example](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entry-form) as a source.

```
{%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.fieldName}}"{% endif -%}>
```

Then I found [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6516/how-can-i-translate-checkboxes-on-a-frontend-user-registration-form-to-lightswit) for checkboxes but for some reason it doesn't seem  to work. I used this in my code (*receiveNewsletter* is a lightswitch in Craft / checbox on the frontend):

```
{%- if account is defined and account.receiveNewsletter == "1" %}checked{% endif -%}
```

But it always seems to return `TRUE`.

And I have no idea how to handle this for select inputs. Can anyone get me back on track please?